# EXPLAIN EXTENDED Results with too much affected Rows

Tags: mysql, explain

I have a query as follows

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM shop.CarInfo A 
LEFT JOIN shop.RegisterInfo B 
  ON A.CarID = B.RegisterInfoID 
LEFT JOIN shop.seller C 
  ON B.RegisterInfoID = C.CarID 
LEFT JOIN shop.CarSeller D 
  ON C.CarSellerID = D.PersonID 
LEFT JOIN shop.Licences E 
  ON B.RegisterInfoID = E.CarID 
LEFT JOIN shop.CarLicences F 
  ON E.CarLicenceID = F.CarLicenceID 
LEFT JOIN shop.CarsLocation G 
  ON A.location = G.CarLocationID 
LEFT JOIN shop.AnnounceStatement H 
  ON B.RegisterInfoID = H.CarID 
LEFT JOIN shop.Announcer I 
  ON H.AnnouncerID = I.AnnouncerID 
WHERE B.title LIKE '%Mercedes%' OR D.name LIKE '%Mercedes%' OR F.Licences LIKE  '%Mercedes%' OR B.RegNo LIKE '%Mercedes%' OR I.name LIKE '%Mercedes%'
```

Unfortunately, this query takes a lot to respond! Using `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`, I got this:

http://i59.tinypic.com/bj9udh.png
[Since I cannot yet upload pics to StackOverflow, I've uploaded to tinypic]

As far as I can see, everything is ok except the first row. Considering that I've created suitable indexes, why so many rows then?

Comment: You are doing `left join`s.  The query has to keep all the rows in `shop.CarInfo` so it is doing a scan of that table.  This doesn't seem unusual.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: You're right. But using INNER JOIN gives 53912 rows for the first row. Still not good enough :(